# Best way to implement Pagination in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, offset-fetch

I have a complex stored procedure that takes a customerId and some other parameters and returns thousands of rows. We want to implement pagination in this SP since the number of rows being returned is pretty huge. There is a main table that has all the product information (more than 100 million rows) and then I have to join it to other tables to get more information about the product. `ProductId` is the primary key in the `Product` table. We have a non-clustered index on `date` with `productId` in the INCLUDE section. There are two approaches that I have in mind. 
**First Method**:
Step 1: Get all the rows for the product id and order by date and stored them in a temp table (#temp1) that will have an identity column as the primary key.
Step 2: Pick the rows based on `@first` and `@last` parameters where `@first = (@page - 1) * @display` and `@last = (@page * @display) + 1` from the temp table created in the previous step and store them in another temp table (#temp2).
Step 3: Join the rows from #temp2 to all the other tables and get the required data.

```
/* @display and @page are passed in along with other input parameters */ 
Declare @first Int = (@page - 1) * @display
Declare @last Int = (@page * @display) + 1

Create Table #temp1 (Id int identity(1,1) primary key, productId uniqueidentifier)
Create Table #temp2 (productId uniqueidentifier)

Insert Into #temp1
Select productId
From dbo.product 
Order by date

Insert into #temp2
Select productId 
From #temp1 
Where id > @first 
  And id < @last 
  
Select *
  From #temp2
  Join some other product tables on product id
```

**Second Method**:
Step 1: Get the rows for the product id ordered by date and have an offset and fetch by clause and store them in a temp table (#temp1).
Step 2: Join the rows from #temp1 to all the other tables and get the required data.

```
/* @display and @page are passed in along with other input parameters */ 
Declare @first Int = (@page - 1) * @display

Create Table #temp1 (productId uniqueidentifier)

Insert Into #temp1
Select productId
From dbo.product 
Order by date
Offset @first rows
fetch next @display rows only

Select *
  From #temp1
  Join some other product tables on product id
```

With method 1, I'll have to load all the data everytime the procedure is called and then filter the rows that I need.
With method 2, I can only fetch the rows i'm interested in but I've read stuff online that offset and fetch can actually slow the query a lot.

Which is usually the best approach for pagination in SQL Server? Of the two methods I described which one would be a better option or is there a better way? Thanks!

Comment: [How To Get Answers To SQL Server Performance Questions](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/how-to-get-answers-to-sql-server-performance-questions/)

Comment: The first option probably, given the right indexes, but minus the temp tables (not sure why they are necessary). This is known as keyset pagination. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/70520457/14868997

Comment: @charlieface the first temp table will get all the sorted rows from the product table. It'll be a clustered index scan on that table. The second temp table will pick the rows based on the page number and display passed in.

Comment: The "sort" on the first table is pointless, it does not affect the final results. You should just paginate by `productid` for example `select top (pageSize) productId from dbo.product where productid > @previousHighest`. See the link I posted

Comment: @Charlieface thanks for the link. I went throught it. A question about keyset pagination - what if the user chooses to click page 4 after page 1? I'll be passing in the last value from page 1. If my understanding is correct, I'll essentially be showing page 2 results on page 4. Does the user have to click every page to get the correct results? How do I overcome that issue and display the correct results for every page?

Comment: You can always paginate `pageSize * 3` to get the next three pages. Or you can guesstimate where the next page starts. Generally users don't skip to page 1million, o it's not really an issue. See also the comments on https://stackoverflow.com/a/19609938/14868997 as well as https://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2013-07/pagination-done-the-postgresql-way